# How to return single object from collection in Laravel API

Tags: php, laravel, api

I am creating an API using Laravel,where i need to return something like this.

```
"course": {
        "English": "99",
        "Math": "67",
        "Foo": "30",
    },
```

I have eloquent relationship which return collection.I am unable to create the desired output.

```
$courses = Course::where('status','active')->get();

This is what i have tried.

course_arr = [];
foreach($courses as $course){
     
            $course_arr[] = array($course->name => $course->marks);
}

return response()->json([
      "course" => (object)$course_arr,
    ],200);

// Output which i am getting.
"GameId": {
    "0": {
        "English": "89"
    },
    "1": {
        "Math": "77"
    },
  
},
```

Can you guys please help me on this.
Thank you.

Comment: push a key value pair instead `container[name] = mark` like so

Comment: @Kevin can you please elaborate this further? i did not get it

Comment: currently, you're pushing  another whole section of an array inside an array: `array[] = [another]`. what you actually need is just a flat array. `myarray[mykeyhere] = myvalue`

Comment: Exactly this is what i needed. Thank you @Kevin. If you can please post the answer here too that may help others as well

Answer (score 0):

The below code will fulfill your requirement.

```php
$courses = Course::where('status', 'active')->pluck('marks', 'name');

return response()->json([
    'course' => $courses
]);
```